# $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{r}{n}))=e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx}.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ be a continuous function. Show that,

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{r=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{r}{n}))=e^{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx}.$

I am taking $A= \displaystyle \prod_{r=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{r}{n}))$ and then taking logarithm. But I don’t get anything from this. I wish to get a integral from a Riemann sum, which we do generally to solve this kind of problems. But here I can’t get anything.

Any kind of help or solution will be very much helpful for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi :) we have $\prod_{r=1}^n|1+f(\frac{r}{n})|=\exp(\ln\prod_{r=1}^n|1+f(\frac{r}{n})|)=\exp(\sum_{r=1}^n\ln |1+f(\frac{r}{n})|)$

Comment: It should be $1+\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)$.